# Angular: ng error when I create an angular project in git-bash

Tags: node.js, angular, git-bash

I Create a folder and run git-bash command there

***$ ng new ng_course***

Actually i tried this first time and it works. But i delete the files when this command downloaded various files. And then i run this command again again but it don't work now.

okay, for the problem solving i tried this

***I deleted the file in c:\users\XXX.angular.json***

i tried this command also:

**npm uninstall -g @angular/cli (add sudo in the start if using Linux)**

**npm cache clean --force / npm cache verify**

**npm install -g @angular/cli**

but it show this message always:

> Project name "ng_course" is not valid. New project names must start
>   with a letter, and must contain only alphanumeric characters or
>   dashes. When adding a dash the segment after the dash must also start
>   with a letter. ng_course

Comment: The error message answer your question.

Comment: Thanks man, I should check it carefully. I solve it now !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can't use `_` in your project name. Instead of that change name to `ng-course` and everything should work. Error mean that, your project name can only contain alphanumeric characters or dashes.